# React - write and read nested objects in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, state

I am developing a React app that takes data from a database on Google's Firebase.

**The database is organized this way:**

```
users {
    user 1 {
        name
        surname
        ... 
    }
    user 2 {
        name
        surname
        ...
    }
}
```

**How I retrieve data in React:**

I take location and instrument from the url to filter the results of the search (using just location for now, but would like to use both), and I successfully manage to get the object printed in the console.

```
componentWillMount(){
    const searchResults = FBAppDB.ref('users');

    let location = this.props.location;
    let instrument = this.props.instrument;

    let profiles = [];
    searchResults.orderByChild('location').equalTo(location).on('value', (snap) => {
        let users = snap.val();
        Object.keys(users).map((key) => {
            let user = users[key];
            console.log(user);
            profiles.push(user);
        });
    });

    // this.setState({users: profiles[0]});
}
```

**console output of the object:**

```
Object {name: "Whatever", surname: "Surrname", ... }
```

What I seem to fail doing is to save these objects (could be more than one) in the state, so I can update the view when the user changes other filters on the page.

I tried to setState the actual user but the state results empty, any idea?

In addition to writing, what would be the best way to get the data back from the state? How do I loop through objects in the state?

Thanks

**EDIT**

This is how my render function looks like:

```
render(){
    return(
        <Row>
            {
                Object.keys(this.state.users).map(function (key) {
                    var user = this.state.users[key];
                    return <SearchResult user={user} />
                })
            }
        </Row>
    );
}
```

I tried to print this.state.users directly, but it doesn't work. Therefore I tried to come up with a (non-working) solution. I'm sorry for any noob mistake here.

Comment: does `SearchResult` expects `user` props to be of the format `{ name: "Whatever", surname: "Surrname", ...}`?

Comment: Yes, it takes the whole object and then I call every property like this.props.user.name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to setState the actual user but the state results empty, any
> idea?

It is because your DB operation `searchResult` is **asynchronous** and JavaScript does not let the **synchronous** codes wait until the async code completes.

In your code, if you enable the commented `setState` invocation, that code will get executed while the async code is waiting for response.

You need to `setState` inside:

```
searchResults.orderByChild('location').equalTo(location).on('value', (snap) => {
    let users = snap.val();
    const profiles = Object.keys(users).map((key) => users[key]);
    this.setState({ users: profiles[0] });
});
```

Whenever you want something to be executed after an async code, put that inside a [callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Using_js-ctypes/Declaring_and_Using_Callbacks) (to the async fn) or use a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

---

> What would be the best way to get the data back from the state? How do I loop through objects in the state?

`setState` can be asynchronous too. But you will get the new updated state on next render. So inside `render()` you can access `users` in the state as `this.state.users` and perform your operations using it.

#### UPDATE:

```
componentWillMount(){
    const searchResults = FBAppDB.ref('users');
    const location = this.props.location;
    const instrument = this.props.instrument;

    searchResults.orderByChild('location').equalTo(location).on('value', (snap) => {
        const users = snap.val();
        const profiles = Object.keys(users).map((key) => users[key]);

        // previously we were setting just profiles[0]; but I think you need 
        // the entire list of users as an array to render as search results
        this.setState({ users: profiles }); // set the whole data to state
    });
}


render(){
    const users = this.state.users || []; // note that this.state.users is an array

    return(
        <Row>
            {
              users.length > 0 
              ? users.map((user) => <SearchResult user={user} />)
              : null
            }
        </Row>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the first part worked really well! As for the second one, I would like to pass each object saved inside this.state.users as a prop for the SearchResult component in the render method. I didn't manage to loop through the objects in the state, any idea?

Comment: can you update the question with the code in your `render()` (where you are trying to render SearchResult component)? I am still unclear about what you actually mean by "loop through the objects in the state"; what are you trying to achieve? please add more clarity to the question.

Comment: Please see the update in answer. Let me know if that works :)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting setState inside the .on(() => ...) just after Object.keys(...). It's an asynchronous call to the server, right? I suppose that setState is called right after the call to the server is made, but before you retrieve any data.